# VSTS Microsoft-Hosted Agent: Virtual Machine size

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-agent

According to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/agents/hosted.md the virtual machine size of the Microsoft-Hosted Agent is:

- Currently utilizing Microsoft Azure general purpose virtual machine sizes (**Standard_DS2_v2 and Standard_DS3_v2**)

What does that mean? Which size is used? Standard_DS2_v2 or Standard_DS3_v2? Can I decide which one I want to use?

Kind regards,

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t the way to force build/release to use DS3_v2 vm agent, it usually try to get DS2v2 sku VM, but sometimes gets a DS3V2 based on availability. We recommend you to setup private agent if hosted agent cannot meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The [current documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations) that it always uses Standard_DS2_V2 for the Microsoft hosted agents.

Alternatively one can use [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) or [scale set agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops), to get more control over what hardware the pipelines run on.

Scale set agents are partially managed by Azure Pipelines, which makes them less work than self-hosted agents, while still providing control over the virtual machines that are used. At the same time they still require quite some work / introduce quite some complexity, so that switching from Microsoft hosted agents to scale set agents should only be done if it is worth it for your organization.